# Simple.Data casting to ToList<string>()

Tags: simple.data

I am using Simple.Data and want to know if I can Select a single column and then cast it to a list of string values. For example using the query below I get the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Simple.Data.SimpleRecord' to 'string'

```
var result = _database.ParentRegionList.All()
            .Select(_database.ParentRegionList.RegionName)
            .Where(_database.ParentRegionList.RegionName.Like(startsWith + "%"))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList<string>();
```

However if I create a class LocationAutoComplete that has a single public property "RegionName" of type string then the cast works fine.

```
var result = _database.ParentRegionList.All()
            .Select(_database.ParentRegionList.RegionName)
            .Where(_database.ParentRegionList.RegionName.Like(startsWith + "%"))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList<LocationAutoComplete>();
```

Comment: Your statement looks buggy. Shouldn't `.Select()` and `.Where()` take a predicate?

Comment: @KenKin, i'd assume that is how the framework they are using works.

Comment: What is the data type of RegionName?  If RegionName is already a varchar or string, you shouldn't have to convert it to string

Comment: RegionName is a varchar in my database

Comment: Correction its an nvarchar(255) sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ToList<T> Simple.Data method expects you to be casting the contents of a SimpleRecord to an object, which is why it works with your LocationAutoComplete class. Full details can be found [here](http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Retrieve/WorkingWithPOCOs.htm).

If you are returning only one field which you wish to return as a scalar value or a list of scalar values, use the ToScalar<T> or ToScalarList<T> method instead. Full details can be found [here](http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Retrieve/ScalarValues.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If RegionName is a varchar then all you need is

```
var result = _database.ParentRegionList.All()                
            .Where(_database.ParentRegionList.RegionName.Like(startsWith + "%"))
            .Select(_database.ParentRegionList.RegionName)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

You don't need the `<string>`

Comment: That gives me a list of SimpleRecord objects, Sorry I also miss read the column type is actually nvarchar

Comment: Try doing the Where before the Select. I'll edit my answer, so you can see

Comment: What if you do a lambda statement in the where clause?  Like so, var result = _database.ParentRegionList.                
            .Where(p=>p.RegionName.Contains(startsWith))
            .Select(p=>p.RegionName)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

Comment: you shouldn't need that All() either